# SceneKit game architecture, communication between ViewControllers

Tags: swift, scenekit

I’m building a `SceneKit` game with three VC’s controlled by a `NavigationController`.

Trying to work out the best way to store the players details (settings and scores). The players details should be updatable by each VC.

I’ve implemented the `MVC` approach with a separate Model class to retrieve the data for the game.

There are:

1. `MainViewController` with character selection and links to other two screens ( + a link to a help screen)
2. `GameViewController` with SceneKit View and Scene and `SpriteKit` HUD overlay.
3. `SettingsViewController` with player results and settings.

I’m thinking of implementing a Player class to hold all the players details that should be accessible to each VC.

Should I pass updates to the players details via a delegate or update the destination VC when the VCs transition using a segue.

There’s partial answer here:
[How to build a multilevel game in SceneKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801550/how-to-build-a-multilevel-game-in-scenekit)

But I’m not sure if this is still the best way to do it.

---

Have researched this more and have a potential solution that might be useful for others.

This is based on Dependency Injection used to propagate state across View Controllers.

This is described well in the following two articles

Matteo Manferdini:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-right-way-to-share-state-between-swift-view-controllers--cms-28474

and Andy Obusek:
http://cleanswifter.com/dependency-injection-with-storyboards/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any posts on this...  hope it helps in some small way.

I use a Data class (sharedInstance) and store my globals there.  I use delegates to communicate between view controllers.  Mostly, I just pass the game state or menu choices in delegates.

A lot depends on the complexity and of course I'm a purest when I can be, but in a real game (not example code), things can get pretty hairy.  You are often dealing with many objects that need to talk to each other such as your players may need to talk with players and other objects.  Loops, threading issues, sound engine, game state - there is a lot going on and it's pretty hard to do without a sharedInstance.

It's great if you can get the perfect design - hats off to those that do, but I try to get 80% with the design and use globals to solve one-off problems.